# Any way to see in EventViewer if a Windows logon was made using password Vs. fingerprint?

Tags: security, login, event-viewer

I suspect someone logged on to my computer (windows 10) (this is someone I know who might have access to my password), I see so many logons that I can't be sure which were mine, but what I do know is that while I do have a 4 digit password setup I always logon using fingerprint. Is there a way to know in the security logs if a logon was made using fingerprint vs. pincode?

Comment: You can look in Microsoft-Windows-Biometrics/Operation for Event ID 1004 (Biometric successful) and compare it with Security event 4624. You'll get list of logins without fingerprint (password and pin alike).

Comment: @Aramil why not post it as answer?

Comment: @Destroy666 lack of time for proper formatting and source check at the moment ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way, but you can check it indirectly:

- First, look in Microsoft-Windows-Biometrics/Operation for Event ID 1004 (Biometric successful)
- Second, look in Security for Event ID 4624 (Successful log in), you can check also 4648 (logged in as additional user)
- Third, compare both lists, that will give you logins where biometrics were not used (both password and PIN)

Further you should check filtered entries for logon types as there still can be some noise. Types 2 and 7 would guarantee that someone entered password/pin from keyboard.
Whole list is available in Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/basic-audit-logon-events

Login audit should be enabled by default (at least successful attempts for older Windows). But in case it is not, you can enable it in Policies: Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Audit Policy.